# HTML - Prefetch resources in anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, prefetch

At the moment, html5 supports [link prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ) for fetching resources before the user accesses it. Frankly, it only supports for the `<link>` tag, but not for anchor tags (`<a>`). Below is the related comment by *MDN*.

> **Are anchor (<a>) tags prefetched?**
>
> No, only <link> tags with a relation type of next or prefetch are
>   prefetched. However, if there is sufficient interest, we may expand
>   link prefetching support to include prefetching <a> tags, which
>   include a relation type of next or prefetch in the future. Doing so
>   would probably help content providers avoid the problem of stale
>   prefetching links.

I would like to know whether there is a way to prefetch resources defined using anchor tags? An approach using javascript, jquery, html5 or angularjs would be really helpful.

Comment: You could try copying the hrefs of all a elements to link elements in the head.

Comment: Thanks and yes that is one way to go. But rather I want to do it programmatically, without accessing or modifying the actual html file. I know it can be done by dynamically adding `<link>` elements with the relevant urls using javascript (correct me if I am wrong). I am wondering is it the only way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, you could try doing it with JavaScript, but I have no idea if the prefetch mechanism will still work if the links are added after the page load rather than during. You don't have a server side language that can insert link elements "live"?